# fetchedObjects (NSArray) count return 0 when it's full of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've 2 managed objects in my core data: `CoreDataTrap` & `CoreDataAllTraps`.
So far, everything regarding updating, adding, deleting, saving etc with CoreDataTrap going well.
But when I try to work with the 2nd managed object `CoreDataAllTraps` I've no error's description, just a simple nil array of fetched objects.

Example for messing with `CoreDataAllTraps`:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil || fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"localizedDescription: %@, userInfo: %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
        success = NO;
    }


    NSLog(@"%s success/fail: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, success?@"yes":@"no");
    NSLog(@"fetchedObjects.count: %d", fetchedObjects.count);
```

> Log this: fetchedObjects.count: 0

I log an error with no details at all, `fetchedObjects.count=0`.
I tried to create a new NSManagedObjectContext and referencing one from AppDelegate, none of them work.

**EDIT:**

1. First time adding (in one class) objects to `CoreDataAllTraps` going well since I log the objects and see the details are correct.
2. My case is `fetchedObjects.count = 0` (in other class).

**EDIT-2:**

Saving from different class (works great):

```
- (void)addOrUpdateTrap:(Traps*)trapObject
{
    int trapID = trapObject.getTrapID;
    CoreDataAllTraps *trapEntity = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trapID == %d", trapID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (results == nil)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    else if ([results count] == 0)
    {
        // Nothing to update, add new trap
        // Create a new record (row)
        trapEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
    else
    {
        trapEntity = results[0]; // There should be only one object for the ID.
    }


    if (trapEntity != nil)
    {
        // Set properties for new or existing object ...

        // Int
        [trapEntity setTrapID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.getTrapID]];
        [trapEntity setType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.getTrapType]];
        [trapEntity setDist:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.getTrapDistanceToCar]];
        [trapEntity setDist_to_close_point:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.getTrapDistanceToClosePoint]];
        [trapEntity setActive:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.isActive]];
        [trapEntity setAlert:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.isAlert]];
        [trapEntity setAlarmDistance:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.alarmDistance]];
        [trapEntity setRoadNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.roadNumber]];
        [trapEntity setPolys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.polygons]];
        [trapEntity setEnter_to_area:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trapObject.getTrapEnterToArea]];

        // Double
        [trapEntity setLat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:trapObject.getTrapLat]];
        [trapEntity setLon:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:trapObject.getTrapLon]];
        [trapEntity setClose_point_lat:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:trapObject.getTrapClosePointLat]];
        [trapEntity setClose_point_lon:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:trapObject.getTrapClosePointLon]];

        // NSString
        [trapEntity setLastTrapAlarm:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", trapObject.getTrapLastAlarm]];
        [trapEntity setPoly0:trapObject.getTrapPolygonA];
        [trapEntity setPoly1: trapObject.getTrapPolygonB];
        [trapEntity setPoly2: trapObject.getTrapPolygonC];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut1: trapObject.getTrapPolygonAzimuthA];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut2: trapObject.getTrapPolygonAzimuthB];
        [trapEntity setPolygonAzimut3: trapObject.getTrapPolygonAzimuthC];
        [trapEntity setDesc: trapObject.getTrapDesc];
        // etc. for all properties ...

        error = nil;
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error] == NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"%s error saving: %@\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Then reading from different class just to ensure all is ok (works great):

```
- (void)saveArray
{
    // [Netroads sharedInstance].arrayOfAllTraps = [dbat getAllTraps];
    [Netroads sharedInstance].arrayOfAllTraps = self.allTraps;
    NSLog(@"[Netroads sharedInstance].arrayOfAllTraps.count: %i", [Netroads sharedInstance].arrayOfAllTraps.count);

    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"fetchedObjects.count: %d", fetchedObjects.count);
```

Log this:

```
fetchedObjects.count: 222
```

**UPDATE-1:**

I tried something else: when i'm saving the objects to core data, i'm calling the function from the end of the original saving function. This way is looks bad but it works. I still look for a beautiful way to mess with the MOC without calling function from the end of different function.

Comment: Have you created any CoreDataAllTraps ?

Comment: There is a difference between `fetchedObjects == nil` (which means an error, and `error` should be set) and `fetchedObjects.count == 0` (which means no error, but results found). - Which case occurs here?

Comment: (Of course I meant "but *no* results found" in my last comment.)

Comment: You did save the context after you added your object, didn't you?. And that "other class", it has the same object context as the class where you added the object?

Comment: I saved the context, then in my new class I allocated a new NSManagedObjectContext.

Comment: This new MOC uses the same store coordinator?

Comment: Yes it is, I also tried to reference it and then use the MOC, still no lock.

Comment: Please provide the `CoreDataAllTraps` insertion code and save

Comment: You say the other code is in methods of a different class.  The method that you say is not working uses `self.managedObjectContext`.  Are you sure has been set correctly?  What is it's value (either in the debugger or via NSLog)?  Are you sure you are using a MOC connected to the same PSC?  If not, is it possible that you are using a nested context and not saving the parent context?

Comment: All of the MOC in my app inherits from AppDelegate. I log the array to see there's are details and I see there's are details.

Comment: What is your context setup architecture? (do you have a background queue parent context?)

Comment: What do you mean? My MOC is setup as it's default setup in a new project. It can be work in background and in foeground, my tests now is in foreground.

Comment: is it possible you are deleting the DB file anywhere?

Comment: Yes, when 1st time loading the app.

Comment: Have you saved the objects in your problematic flow prior to executing the query? provide the insertion and save code of the problematic flow.

Comment: One problem chasing another, what I think the problem is: accessing NSManagedObjectContext from multiple places at the same time.

Comment: You can't access the MOC from multiple places at the same time, a MOC is not thread safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSManagedObjectContext work well only a few times, then it stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855893/nsmanagedobjectcontext-work-well-only-a-few-times-then-it-stops-working)